# Custom UTM coordinates to ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, openstreetmap, ggmap

On maps obtained from osm/cloudmade etc using `get_map`, how does one change the projection to a custom UTM coordinate using Proj4/CRS?

Can something like

```
pc0.1<- spTransform(pc0,CRS("+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs+ellps=WGS84+towgs84=0,0,0"))
```

be used with the `get_map` or `ggmap` or ggplot in general?
Is there any way other than changing all my UTM to match the LL?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have done this previously when using `library(OpenStreetMap)` with the command `openproj`, but I'm not sure if this exists in the `ggmap` library. I generally found that `OpenStreetMap` gave me more additional functionality than `ggmap`.